# Simulate button click on a Bluetooth receiver with an ESP32

Tags: resistors, bluetooth, esp32

I bought a [Bluetooth audio module](https://www.amazon.se/dp/B085NRZH87?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details) that I want to control from my ESP32. To control it you change the resistor value of the KEY input to ground.

My first thought was to add a transistor with the correct resistor and turn it on with an GPIO of the ESP32, but I'm not sure of the output voltage of the module. Is this posible, and if not, how would you solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: The outputs of ESP32 are already made of transistors. What's the VCC for the module? Do you know how it works? Have you measured what's the voltage on KEY pin?

Comment: KEY seems to be an analog input with an internal pull-up resistor. You can calculate the pull-up by pressing the individual buttons and measuring the voltage applied to the KEY input.

Comment: I'm quite certain you could replace a physical button with a [2N7002K](https://www.vishay.com/docs/71333/2n7002k.pdf).

Comment: Please provide a link to a technical data sheet for the Bluetooth device.

Comment: https://easyeda.com/editor#id=b9274d07206c4f4bb420139e369a4a1e
https://oshwlab.com/Ratti3/mh-m18-bluetooth-audio-receiver-module

This was the best i could find, i get my board today so i will mesure as  you described abow

Comment: The output off KEY is 3.5V. And im powering the VCC with 5v from usb